# Combine strings in multidimensional array and keep key - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
array(1) {
  ["comments"]=>
  array(244) {
    [113]=>
      array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(40) "2016-07-15 09:27 | From On Track to Done"
      [1]=>
      string(40) "2016-07-15 09:56 | From Done to On Track"
     }
  }
}
```

And I want to make into this array:

```
array(1) {
  ["comments"]=>
    array(244) {
    [113]=>
      array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(80) "2016-07-15 09:27 | From On Track to Done 
      2016-07-15 09:56 | From Done to On Track"
      }
   }
}
```

I need to keep the key [113] and merge the values.
I need all the comments to be in only one array.
In this example there are only two comments, but actually it is much more.

I tried with array_merge, array_value and a loop. I couldnt get it.

Comment: String values are imploded with `implode` function

Comment: Post the code of your attempts with "array_merge and array_value and a loop". Your code will give us a start point.

Comment: Landra, if any of the answers below is useful, you can click its checkmark to accept it (this way you reward people's effort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general algorithm would be :

```
<?php
// SAMPLE DATA.
$arr = array( "comments" => array( 0 => array( "2016-07-15 09:27 | From On Track to Done",
                                               "2016-07-15 09:56 | From Done to On Track"
                                             ),
                                   1 => array( "111 | aaa",
                                               "222 | bbb",
                                               "333 | ccc"
                                             )
                                 ),
              "posts"    => array( 0 => array( "2016-07-13 08:00 | bla bla bla",
                                               "2016-07-13 08:30 | more bla bla bla"
                                             ),
                                   1 => array( "444 | xxx",
                                               "555 | yyy",
                                               "666 | zzz"
                                             )
                                 )
            );
var_dump( $arr ); // ORIGINAL ARRAY.
$new = array();
foreach ( $arr as $key => $category ) // "COMMENTS", "POSTS", ...
{ for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $category ); $i++ ) // 0, 1, ...
  { $values = implode( $category[ $i ]," " ); // MERGE STRINGS.
    $new[ $key ][ $i ] = array( $values );//WE CAN REMOVE "ARRAY" AND LEAVE ONLY "$VALUES".
  }
}
var_dump( $new ); // NEW ARRAY.
?>
```

Result :

**original array**

```
array (size=2)
  'comments' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '2016-07-15 09:27 | From On Track to Done' (length=40)
          1 => string '2016-07-15 09:56 | From Done to On Track' (length=40)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '111 | aaa' (length=9)
          1 => string '222 | bbb' (length=9)
          2 => string '333 | ccc' (length=9)
  'posts' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '2016-07-13 08:00 | bla bla bla' (length=30)
          1 => string '2016-07-13 08:30 | more bla bla bla' (length=35)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '444 | xxx' (length=9)
          1 => string '555 | yyy' (length=9)
          2 => string '666 | zzz' (length=9)
```

**new array**

```
array (size=2)
  'comments' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2016-07-15 09:27 | From On Track to Done 2016-07-15 09:56 | From Done to On Track' (length=81)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '111 | aaa 222 | bbb 333 | ccc' (length=29)
  'posts' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2016-07-13 08:00 | bla bla bla 2016-07-13 08:30 | more bla bla bla' (length=66)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '444 | xxx 555 | yyy 666 | zzz' (length=29)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your array structure, but simple solution is:

```
$vals = implode("\n", $ar['comments'][113]);
$ar['comments'][113] = array();
$ar['comments'][113][] = $vals;
```

Or simpler:

```
$ar['comments'][113] = array(implode("\n", $ar['comments'][113]));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! You were right. I didn't thought about implode. I used your answer and made it into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array['comments'][113] = implode(' ', $array['comments'][113]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help! You were right. It was with implode.

The answer was this:

```
foreach ($goals["comments"] as $key => $value) {
    $goals['comments'][$key][0] = implode($value, "\n");
}
```